# Под мухой?

Tags: фразеология

О выпившем человеке можно услышать, что он по мухой. Откуда пошло это выражение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По Виноградову выражение пришло к нам из жаргона картёжников и военных под влиянием игры муха, или мушка.

Подробнее по ссылке http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/wordhistory/20/%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%94

Comment: Очень  интересная  статья.  Я -то  всю  жизнь  думал, что  дядюшка  Онегина  просто  дурью  маялся,  мух  на  окне  давил.  Оказывается -  не  всё  так  плохо.  В  связи  с  выражением  "задавить  муху"  вспоминается  и  другое - "заморить  червячка"  с  похожим  значением.  Настойчивое  желание  выпить  можно  сравнить  с  назойливостью  мухи.  Получается  обычный  художественный  образ.  Можно  и  без  карточного  жаргона  обойтись.

Answer (score 2):

прежде чем понять, какое отношение мухи имеют к состоянию опьянения, несколько слов об арабской грамматике. Самая распространенная приставка в арабском — М. С помощью ее образуются причастия действительные и страдательные, имена места, времени, орудия и т.д. В русском языке ей соответствует в ряде случаев приставка по, например, покос — имя места и времени косьбы. Иногда она проявляется в сохранившемся виде, то есть тоже в форме М, например, слово место происходит от есть, точно так же, как в арабском: макян “место” от кян “быть”, буквально: “место бытия”. В слове миска тоже сокрыта арабская формула имени орудия или сосуда, преобразующая корень СКЙ “лить, поить” в имя сосуда, то есть то, чем пьют, из чего хлебают или поливают. И все же в русском более употребительна в этом значении приставка по. Таким образом, устанавливается равнозначность начальных согласных М и П при сопоставлениях между русским и арабским. Значит, мотмайих (диалектное произношение), в арабской графике “качающийся”, может дать в русском рефлекс с начальным П, если же учесть еще, что долгое арабское А в других языках, например, еврейском, персидском, дает 0(У), то достаточно оснований, чтобы в выражении под мухой признать арабское мутама 'их (классическое произношение), тем более что значение подходит как нельзя лучше.

Надо сказать, что описанный случай — не единственный пример маскировки начала этой арабской грамматической модели под русскую приставку или предлог под. Возьмем русское слово подхалим. Что оно значит? Русскому человеку кажется, что оно состоит и на этот раз из приставки под- и корня халим. Но что означает халим? Других слов в русском языке с этим корнем нет. Единственное утешение для филолога, это то, что бессмыслица для русского языка — обычное явление. Случай такой, как и остальные, сколько ни ломай голову, ничего не придумаешь, если не знаешь арабского языка. Зная теперь, что приставка под — просто маскировка, смотрим в арабском словаре, что означает мутахалим. Оказывается, это тот, кто прикидывается кротким, послушным, как это обычно и делает подхалим. Подхалим и под мухой — это формы одной грамматической модели, которая в арабской грамматике называется причастием шестой породы.

Любопытно, что в древнегреческом языке эта форма маскируется под приставку мета, например, метафизик — это тот, кто пытается выглядеть красноречивым и логичным. Так что, метафизика — это не то, что за физикой, как пытаются убедить окружающих философы, а потуги на красноречие и логичность. Первым, кто раскусил метафизику, был Гегель, который называл ее антидиалектикой, а он знал, что говорил. http://otvet.mail.ru/question/17200384

Comment: А  какой - нибудь  другой  язык ( поближе  к  русскому )  примерить  не  пробовали ?

Comment: Очень интересная статья, но как-то сомнительно... При чём тут арабская грамматика?

Comment: **Ищущий полезные знания**, это всё очень интересно, действительно. 

Но напрашивается вопрос, ГДЕ и КОГДА **русские** люди могли позаимствовать эти **арабские** слова?

.

Арабы живут очень уж далеко от Руси-матушки. :-)

Answer (score 0):

А может быть "под мухой" означает находиться под действием мухомора? Находим в Википедии: "Мухомор красный использовался как опьяняющее вещество..." Главным образом использовался предками в лечебных целях. Опьянение было побочным эффектом.